# Issuing errors in C

Tags: c

I was looking for the standard  way to issue errors in C programs.
What is the best way:

1. use fprintf to stderr and exit with a code or
2. User error function as explained [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html#Error-Messages).

Thanks.

Comment: Imho this depends, if you want to implement some kind of recovery, specefic cleanup functions and (lovely) jumps might be necessary.
If you want it just to crash and simple assert will do.
Using errno.h functions is pretty cool as well as it gives you idea what crashed and why (in library functions or in your own if you decide to implement errno variable and set appropriate values for errors).

Answer (score 0):

Depends: (1) is portable, (2) is GNU/Linux-specific but maybe convenient. So, it depends on how portable your program must be.

You can also use the `error` function and ship a portable version of it with your program for users of other platforms. You will then have to store the program name in a global variable somewhere in `main`.

Comment: U mean posix (pretty much all *NIXes) specific.

Comment: @AoeAoe: `error` is not in the POSIX spec. It's not in Mac OS X, AFAICT.

Comment: afaik macosx is fully compliant posix OS (they used code from bsd 4.3). That would mean that their C library has perror.

Comment: @AoeAoe: the OP asked about the `error` function, which is a GNU extension. `perror` is ISO C.

Answer (score 0):

```
What is the best way:

 - use `fprintf()` to stderr and exit with a code or
 - Use `perror()` function as explained here.
```

First of all, you should exit in both cases, assuming they are unrecoverable errors. You should exit with the function exit() in stdlib.h:

```
exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
```

The error code returned matters for the operating system, and is no the same on in all of them.

About your exact question, using `fprintf()` for printing to `stderr` is correct, you can issue all kind of errors (those recognized by `errno` and others), and gives you the freedom of producing your own message errors. Using `perror()` produces a standard error message that you cannot change.